# wicked-pdf hangs server when generating file

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-3.2, wicked-pdf

On a rails 3.2.18 application, with wicked_pdf (0.11.0) and wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.3) declared in the gem file, mime-types.rb was **not** amended to include`Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf` otherwise, on startup of Thin on osX development platform, the following warning is given:

```
/Users/it/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@app/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant PDF
```

An initializer states

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

The path `/usr/local/bin` does include an alias  to wkhtmltopdf.  In a show view:

```
  def show
    @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'pdf' } # show.html.erb
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "invoice_name"
      end
      format.json { render json: @transaction }
    end
  end
```

The show view renders appropriately.  Append the path with `.pdf` and the console registers:

```
"***************[\"/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf\", \"-q\", \"file:///var/folders/kV/kVDOSPkcEuqSVnTjenAVRE+++TI/-Tmp-/wicked_pdf20141018-1401-m614pd.html\", \"/var/folders/kV/kVDOSPkcEuqSVnTjenAVRE+++TI/-Tmp-/wicked_pdf_generated_file20141018-1401-1hor23g.pdf\"]***************"
```

And the server hangs.  It gets interrupted with `ctrl-c` and then the server console adds:

```
[...]
Rendered transactions/show.pdf.erb (12.1ms)
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data invoice_name.pdf  (18.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 36322.7ms (Views: 15.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
Exiting
```

which it did not do.  Other attempts to simply generate a file and save it have led to non-production of the PDF file, but without hanging the Thin server. So the engines are not all running properly...

What is wrong with the set-up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recalling having run successfully wicked-pdf in the past, the answer to what is different provided the solution:  **removing the initializer** allows the process to run its course.

Comment: You ever find a solution @jerome? Having the same issue.

Comment: In my case, as I stated, I had an initializer, that `exe_path`, which gummed things up.  I recalled I had just added that and thus attempted removing it.  The process ran its expected course and thus the problem was with that initializer.  I admit it is not a good explanation, just a pointer to the guilty party.